# laravel Undefined variable: :

Tags: laravel-5.1

i get this error i don't no why
the line between section id and books

Undefined variable: section (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\resources\views\books\create_book.blade.php)

the link  `<a href="{{url('admin_book/createbook',$section->id)}}"class="btn btn-success">New Book</a>`

my create_book.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admin_book/store','method'=>'POST','files'=>'true']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('section_id',$section->id) !!}
<div class="form-group ">
{!! Form::label('Book Title', 'Enter the Title of Book:') !!}
{!! Form::text("book_title",'',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
 <div class="form-group ">
{!! Form::label('Book Edition', 'Enter the Edition of Book:') !!}
{!! Form::text("book_edition",'',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
 <div class="form-group ">
{!! Form::label('Book Description', 'Enter the Description of Book:') !!}
{!! Form::textarea("book_description",'',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('upload', 'Upload an Image:') !!}
{!! Form::file('image','',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Create',['class'=>'btn btn-info btn-block']) !!}
 </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and my booksControllers

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('books.create_book');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $book_title = $request ->input('book_title');
        $book_edition = $request ->input('book_edition');
        $book_description = $request ->input('book_description');
        $file = $request ->file('image');
        $destinationPath = 'images';
        $filename = $file ->getClientOriginalName();
        $file ->move($destinationPath,$filename);

        $section_id = $request -> section_id;


        $new_book = new Book;
        $new_book ->book_title = $book_title;
        $new_book ->book_edition = $book_edition;
        $new_book ->book_description = $book_description;
        $new_book ->image_name = $filename;

        $new_book ->section_id = $section_id;

        $new_book ->save();
        return redirect('admin_book/'.$section_id);
    }
```

and my route

```
Route::get('admin_book/createbook','BooksController@create');
```

Comment: You aren't passing `$section` to your view: `return view('books.create_book');` You need to have a `->with(["section" => $section]);` to be able to use it in your view.

Comment: i got this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\resources\views\books\create_book.blade.php) when i put this                                       $section = Section::all(); return view('books.create_book')->with(["section" => $section]);

Comment: You're returning all `Sections`, and they're in an array... So `$section[0]->id`, no `$section->id`.

Comment: thank you very much good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the `$section` variable to your view. You have to retrieve the variable from the database and pass it to the view like this:

```
public function create() {
    //Retrieve from database
    $section = Section::all(); 
    //Pass the collection to the view
    return view('books.create_book')->with('section', $section);
}
```

Comment: i got this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\resources\views\books\create_book.blade.php) when i put this $section = Section::all(); return view('books.create_book')->with(["section" => $section]);

Comment: I don't think `with(["section" => $section]);` is correct. Try like it's in my answer, without array: `>with('section', $section);`.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Lewis has pointed out, you haven't passed in the `$section` variable when you have created the view.

Your create method, should look like this:

```
public function create()
    {
        //Logic that gets the section goes here
        //Stored in the $section variable

        return view('books.create_book', ['section' => $section]);
    }
```

This will solve your error as `Undefined variable: section` is telling you that within your view, a variable named `section` does not exist. Simply pass it through and it will.

Comment: i got this error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\resources\views\books\create_book.blade.php)  when i put this         $section = Section::all();
        return view('books.create_book')->with(["section" => $section]);